# Inserting tag on attribute value in XSLT

Tags: xml, attributes, xslt-2.0

I'm experimenting with XSLT to display some results I'm getting as XML (the idea is to generate a decent HTML for a QWebView).

I'm a beginner with XSLT and I can't figure how to obtain the following result. (This is an example)

**Input**

```
<object name="object_name">
    <property1 diff="modified">value1</property1>
    <property2>value2</property2>
</object>
```

**Output**

```
<p>object_name</p>
<ul>
    <li>
        property1 = <span style="color : #ff00000 ; font-weight : bold ;">value1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        property2 = value2
    </li>
</ul>
```

So I want to add a "span" tag whenever I encounter a "diff" attribute (and adapt style to attribute value)

For now, I am doing something like this :

```
    <xsl:template match="object">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="@object_name"/>
        </p>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="object/*">
        <li>
            <xsl:sequence select="local-name(.)"/> = <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
```

And I get what I want except for the "span" tag... I can't find how to make it work...
Here is the kind of code snippet I tried to write and plug there, but   unsuccessfully :

```
<xsl:template match="*[@diff = 'modified']">
    <span style="color : #ff0000 ; font-weight : bold ;">iDontKnowWhatToWrite</span>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks in advance for any piece of advice or redirection

EDIT : Adding a precision : Thanks for the idea of getting the attribute value match in the object/* match, but I would like to find a solution with a separate match as I will use this same match for other tags...

I don't know if I'm very clear... In fact, this XSLT will process XML with  tags like the one I showed, but there will be several tags with different output, like  and , but for now I'm working on the first kind, but I wish to keep this "diff" attribute behavior for the entire document (anytime it's encountered, I would like to embed the following in a "span" tag)

Comment: Why don't you put the `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` inside of the `span` element?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="object">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="@object_name"/>
        </p>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="object/*">
        <li>
            <xsl:sequence select="local-name(.)"/> = <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@diff = 'modified'">
                    <span style="color : #ff00000 ; font-weight : bold ;">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </span>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or you can use this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="object">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="@object_name"/>
        </p>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="object/*">
        <li>
            <xsl:sequence select="local-name(.)"/> = <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@diff = 'modified']">
        <li>
            <xsl:sequence select="local-name(.)"/> = <span style="color : #ff00000 ; font-weight : bold ;"><xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually edited my post, because I could have done this, but I'm searching for a more "generic" solution that I can reuse for other tags... maybe a template with parameter ? (I'm just learning about this possibility)

Comment: Well, thank you! I actually used a mix of your first proposition and this idea of template with parameter. I will post my solution below

Answer (score 0):

As I explained in the EDIT of my question, I needed a more generic solution than the one proposed as answers/comments.
Here is what I did, coupling conditional choose/when/otherwise structure and template parameters.

```
<xsl:template match="object">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="@object_name"/>
    </p>
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object/*">
    <li>
        <xsl:sequence select="local-name(.)"/> = <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@diff = 'modified']">
    <li>
        <xsl:sequence select="local-name(.)"/> = 
        <xsl:call-template name="processContent">
            <xsl:with-param name="contentValue"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="diffAttr"><xsl:value-of select="@diff"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="processContent">
    <xsl:param name="contentValue" />
    <xsl:param name="diffAttr" select="" />

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$diffAttr = 'modified'">
            <span style="color : #ff0000 ; font-weight : bold ;">
                <xsl:value-of select="$contentValue"/>
            </span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$contentValue"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

(This is the most generic solution for me, as I will be able to reuse this template for other tags, and I can even extend it easily to other diff attribute values)